# Wkhtmltopdf SVG Padding

Tags: svg, raphael, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to add padding around SVG figures that are drawn via Raphael, and am seeing the following from wkhtmltopdf. Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Is padding supported on SVG elements?

[image: This is what it looks like rendered in HTML]
[image: This is the wkhtmltopdf output]

Comment: If you mean padding in the CSS sense, then no.  In SVG you have to explicitly state the dimensions of things. There is no autmatic layout as in HTML.

Comment: I'd just use a workaround - if you know the background color, place the image inside a `div` with the same background color and a little padding.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can add padding and other styling rules to your Raphael-created SVG elements.  It's just another element in the DOM -- there's no need for a workaround.  @BigBadaboom's assertion is only true for elements inside the SVG element, not the SVG element itself.

```
<style type="text/css">
    svg.padding-please
    {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

And when you create your Raphael paper objects:

```
var paper = Raphael( 'container', width, height );
jQuery( paper.canvas ).attr( "class", "padding-please" );  // `canvas` gives us direct access to the DOM node
```

**Alternative Approach**

You could always whip up a simple Raphael extension to add a specified amount of margin to a given SVG by manipulating the viewbox.  For instance:

```
Raphael.fn.addMargin = function addMargin( ratio )
{
    var contentBox = { x: 100000, y: 100000, width: 0, height: 0 };
    this.forEach(   function( element )
                    {
                        var elemBox = element.getBBox();
                        contentBox.x = Math.min( contentBox.x, elemBox.x );
                        contentBox.y = Math.min( contentBox.y, elemBox.y );
                        contentBox.width = Math.max( contentBox.width, elemBox.width );
                        contentBox.height = Math.max( contentBox.height, elemBox.height );
                    }, this );

    if ( contentBox.x == 100000 )   //  No elements?  Whatevs
        return;
    var xMargin = contentBox.width * ratio;
    var yMargin = contentBox.height * ratio;
    this.setViewBox( contentBox.x - xMargin, contentBox.y - yMargin, contentBox.width + xMargin * 2, contentBox.height + xMargin * 2 );
}
```

Then if you wanted to add a 10% margin to a given SVG, you would just call

```
paper.addMargin( 0.1 );
```

There are so many ways to skin cats, it's amazing Felis catus isn't extinct =)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Actually just implemented your second suggestion a few hours ago. :) For some reason even though padding works in the browser, when using phantomjs or wkhtmltopdf it isn't handled the same way.